# MIPS assembly peculiarities

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to compile a list of MIPS architecture peculiarities, and so far has come up with

- out of order execution due to branch delay
- out of order execution due to load delay

Am I overlooking anything that could throw me off when reading a MIPS assembly listing?  My background is only Intel/i386).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MIPS is much more orthogonal than x86 could ever dream of being.  Just about every instruction can be done with any input and output register and usually only takes 1 cycle - and where it doesn't it is easy to tell.  Beyond that, they use Load as a pnumonic instead of Move and have a more straight forward addressing system (bye bye word ptr), but I call all of the above advantages.  The out of order things you've mentioned are the only things I can think of in terms of gotchas that are way unexpected.

Comment: From my testing, if you have something like `bnez $t0,$t1,foo` followed by `move $t0,$t1`, the branch is still taken since the test is "locked in" before the move takes place, yet by the time the branch actually occurs they are equal. That's probably the only other gotcha I can think of